# Verizon Galaxy Note 4 with usb debugging on not recognized by android studio on centos7

Tags: android, android-studio, centos7, samsung-galaxy

I've been running Android Studio on my CentOS7 (not Windows) laptop for a while now.  I was able to debug my app running on a Verizon Galaxy Note 3.  I've now moved up to a Verizon Galaxy Note 4.  I enabled Developer Options and I turned on USB Debugging.

However, when I have it look for running devices to run my app, it doesn't show up in the list ("Nothing to show").

What else do I need to do?

Comment: try this command in your terminal : adb kill-server  , then close or disconnect your device   After reconnecting run this  adb start-server

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  The "kill" command takes process ids.

Comment: Thanks, but no change.  Still doesn't see the device.

Comment: Someone on #android-dev said that galaxy phones running Marshmallow have this symptom on Linux.

Comment: did you close eclipse/android studio before running the commands?

Comment: I did now.  No change. The other odd thing is that when I plug in the phone to the laptop, it shows it's charging,but I thought I was supposed to get some sort of notification about USB debugging.  I don't see that.